# How do I sort a datagridview column with custom parameters for vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I have a datagridview (dgRequests) on one of my forms. It only has two columns- date and status. The status can show 1 of 3 options:

1.Open
2.Pending
3.Closed

I would like to sort the datagridview by latest date first, but Open above Pending and Pending above Closed.

I've done some research but all I can find is this snippet of code:

```
dgRequests.Sort(dgRequests.Columns("Status"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of specifying what keyword or code I can use to sort the column with the parameters above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Datatable and a BindingSource you could add an Expression Column to the table with and expression that looks like IIF([Status] = 'Open', 1, IIF([Status] = 'Pending', 2, IIF([Status] = 'Closed', 3, 0))).  Then you could set the BindingSource.Sort property to "DateCol DESC, SortCol"